# How to create new windows for subsequent matplotlib plots?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graph

Currently using Python 3.6.0 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Dec 23 2016, 11:57:41) on Windows (64 bits).

I want a procedure that I am writing to generate two different plots. One plot will have three separate graphs and then I want a separate window that shows a histogram.

```
plt.subplot(311)
plt.plot(z)
plt.xlabel('Time(s)', fontsize=14)
plt.ylabel('Amplitude(v)', fontsize=8)
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=.5)
plt.figure
plt.subplot(312)
plt.plot(timey[0:(len(freq))//2],y)
plt.xlabel('Frequency(Hz)', fontsize=14)
plt.ylabel('Amplitude(V)', fontsize=8)
plt.subplot(313)
plt.plot(fre, psd)
plt.xlabel('Frequency(Hz)', fontsize=14)
plt.ylabel('Power Spectrum Density(Watts/Hz)', fontsize =8)
plt.show()
np.savetxt( file ,y, delimiter='  ',newline='  ')
plt.savefig('FFT'+i+'.png', bbox_inches='tight')
wait = input("PRESS ENTER TO CONTINUE.")   #an attempt at breakpoints
plt.figure
plt.subplot(111)
plt.plot(bin[0:bnn],his)
plt.show()
plt.savefig('Histogram'+i+'.png', bbox_inches='tight')
```

Even using `plt.figure()`, I still plot overtop of existing plots unless I use `plt.subplot(111)`, which erases the original plot and places the new one in the same window. I am hoping to generate two separate windows. I have read several previous questions to no avail. I tried using `%matplotlib qt` or what I have imported *mpl* as, but also no use. Perhaps I do not understand the syntax for this?

Comment: Are you sure to call `plt.figure()` (with the parenthesis)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First note that `plt.figure` does nothing. You would need to call `plt.figure()`. However, this is not solving the actual problem.

Since the old figure with 3 subplots is still the current figure at the point you want to start a new one, `plt.figure()` will simply get you the old figure.

To get a new figure, use a new figure number.

```
plt.figure(2)
```